# Grammar for recursive descent parsing

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

Is there an easy way to tell whether a simple grammar is suitable for recursive descent? Is eliminating left recursion and left factoring the grammar enough to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.

To build a recursive descent parser (without backtracking), you need to eliminate or resolve all predict conflicts. So one definitive test is to see if the grammar is LL(1); LL(1) grammars have no predict conflicts, by definition. Left-factoring and left-recursion elimination are necessary for this task, but they might not be sufficient, since a predict conflict might be hiding behind two competing non-terminals:

```
 list  ::= item list'
 list' ::= ε 
         | ';' item list'
 item  ::= expr1
         | expr2
 expr1 ::= ID '+' ID
 expr2 ::= ID '(' list ')
```

The problem with the above (or, at least, one problem) is that when the parser expects an `item` and sees an `ID`, it can't know which of `expr1` and `expr2` to try. (That's a predict conflict: Both non-terminals could be predicted.) In this particular case, it's pretty easy to see how to eliminate that conflict, but it's not really left-factoring since it starts by combining two non-terminals. (And in the full grammar this might be excerpted from, combining the two non-terminals might be much more difficult.)

In the general case, there is no algorithm which can turn an arbitrary grammar into an LL(1) grammar, or even to be able to say whether the language recognised by that grammar has an LL(1) grammar as well. (However, it's easy to tell whether the grammar itself is LL(1).) So there's always going to be some art and/or experimentation involved.

I think it's worth adding that you don't really need to eliminate left-recursion in a practical recursive descent parser, since you can usually turn it into a while-loop instead of recursion. For example, leaving aside the question of the two `expr` types above, the original grammar in an extended BNF with repetition operators might be something like

```
list ::= item (';' item)*
```

Which translates into something like:

```
def parse_list():
    parse_item()
    while peek(';'):
        match(';')
        parse_item()
```

(Error checking and AST building omitted.)

Comment: _In this particular case, it's pretty easy to see how to eliminate that conflict, but it's not really left-factoring since it starts by combining two non-terminals._ It would be nice to know what that refactoring is called ("item : ID '+' ID | ID '(' list ')'" => "item : ID ('+' ID | '(' list ')')"). I haven't found a name so I call it "grouping" because it's combining alts with an EBNF group.